# invertible immersion is a diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry

Show that an invertible immersion $\varphi$:N $\to$ M is a diffeomorphism. Give a counterexample to this statement if N does not have a countable basis. 
I think I can use the Constant Rank Theorem. Since it is invertible, the dimension of N and M should be same.Then we know it is a diffeomorphism, but seems it has nothing to do with a countable basis? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think there is a counter example without countability?

Comment: Cause it asks for the counterexample...It seems if it is not second countable, the dimension of N and M could be different.

Comment: What is "it" in "it asks"?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take $N$ to be ${\mathbb R}$ with discrete topology.

Comment: why this one is locally euclidean to R so it is a manifold?

Comment: It is a manifold, but is not locally $R$; think, what is its dimension?

Comment: under the usual topology of $R^n$,if the map between R with discrete topology and $R^n$ is identity map, then it is not an open map since a dot is not open.

Comment: Yes that will be a $0$-dimensional manifold but how is differentiability defined so that we can even talk about immersions ? @MoisheKohan

Comment: @Something: Smoothness for 0-dimensional manifolds was discussed several times at MSE, for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2801680/smooth-structure-of-a-zero-dimensional-manifold), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133613/uniqueness-of-smooth-structure-on-a-zero-dimensional-smooth-manifold). The bottom line is that every map of a 0-dimensional manifold to another manifold will be smooth.