# Smooth structure of a zero-dimensional manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Given the discrete space $X$ and the atlas $A=\{(\{x\},\varphi_x)|x\in X\}$, where 
$$\varphi_x:\{x\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^0,x\mapsto 0,$$

in what sense is the transition map $\varphi_x\circ\varphi_x^{-1}=id_{\mathbb{R}^0}$ smooth? It eludes me how differentiability is defined for a one-point set.

Does it have to do with the fact that since $\mathbb{R}^0$ is 0-dimensional, any map on it has zero components and therefore no partial derivatives?

Comment: Write down a good definition of differentiability for $\mathbb R^n$.  See what it means for $\mathbb R^0$.  Take into account the meaning of quantification over the empty set.  I think you will conclude that the unique map $\mathbb R^0 \to \mathbb R^0$ is differentiable.

Comment: A function $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable at $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^m$, if there exists a linear map $L:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, such that

$\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\|f(x_0+h)+f(x_o)-L(h)\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}}{\|h\|_{\mathbb{R}^m}}=0.$

On $\mathbb{R}^0$ we can pick $L:\mathbb{R}^0\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^0,0\mapsto0$. But then I do not comprehend how to evaluate the limit, given that the only possible norm is $\|0\|=0$.

Comment: OK, your definition has $\lim_{h \to 0}$ in it.  That involves quantifying over all $h$ satisfying some conditions, including $h \ne 0$.  Since there are no such $h$, the relevant statement is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK answering based on my comments.

I have some formula $\psi(h)$ involving $h \in \mathbb R^n$ with values $\psi(h) \in \mathbb R$.  Any formula at all.  I claim, when $n=0$, the statement
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \psi(h) = 0
$$
is vacuously true.  Indeed, it means:

For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $h$ with $0 < \|h\| < \delta$ we have $|\psi(h)| < \epsilon$.

This is vacuouslsy true, of course, since in $\mathbb R^0$ there are no $h$ satisfying $0 < \|h\| < \delta$.  I don't even have to look at the formula $\psi(h)$.

Comment: In fact, it is also vacuously true that $\lim_{h \to 0} \psi(h) = 17$, but that is irrelevant.