# Is there any general theory about existence of smooth structures of a topological manifold?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I've read that there exists some topological manifold (of dimension $>3$) either with no smooth structure or having some multiple non-diffeomorphic smooth structures.

How to show that the topological manifold $\mathbb{R}^4$ has no smooth structure?
And also what is about higher dimensions?

Is there any general theory about the existence of smooth structures of a topological manifold?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^4$ *has* a smooth structure

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992956/how-to-choose-a-standard-smooth-structure-for-a-manifold) on Simon Donaldson and Michael Freedman in 1984 and the links given there. Try to search bit on this site here, there are many posts about this topic.

Comment: Yes, there is such a general theory. As a starting point you can look at Milnor's paper "Differential topology, 46 years later".